# Select MySQL with max characters

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
ID | User | Name
1  | Usr1 | First User Name
2  | Usr2 | Another User Name
```

How to select NAME from USER with max characters = 7

```
Name from Usr1 = "First U"
Name from Usr2 = "Another"
```

Comment: You mean only the first 7 characters? Review the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).  `LEFT()` or `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) mysql function.

```
SELECT left(name, 7) FROM user
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the question but here's what I've got:

If you want to get the **NAME with 7 char** then here's the syntax:

```
SELECT NAME FROM USER
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(NAME) = 7
```

Now, if you want to get the the **first 7** char, here's the syntax:

```
SELECT LEFT(NAME, 7) FROM USER;
```